# Advanced regex replacement. Check if in <script> tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a simple regex which checks an entire string for a function declaration. So in this code:

```
public function Test($name)
{
    echo 'In test';
}
```

It will find the first part:

```
function Test($name)
{
```

And it replaces that with a custom piece:

```
function Test($name)
{
    echo 'New piece';
```

Which eventually makes my code look like this:

```
public function Test($name)
{
    echo 'New piece';
    echo 'In test';
}
```

This all works perfectly fine with this regex:

```
preg_match_all ( '/function(.*?)\{/s', $source, $matches )
```

---

The problem is, is that i want to ignore everything when the regex sees a script tag. So in this case, this source:

```
public function Test($name) //<--- Match found!
{
    echo 'In test';
}

<script type="text/javascript"> //<--- Script tag found, dont do any matches!
$(function() {
    function Test()
    {
        var bla = "In js";
    }
});
</script> //<--- Closed tag, start searching for matches again.

public function Test($name) //<--- Match found!
{
    echo 'In test';
}
```

How can i do this in my regex?

Comment: It is too complex. Cannot be done with just a single `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: extract all js data first and then run you script and then append your script data again.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary That's actually a nice solution aswell. Could you give that as a real answer? I might accept that if no one else comes with a better suggestion.

Comment: @Vivendi as per the complexity of your question it is difficult to give the correct solution at one short. Me too have to research over this :)

Comment: If you're just injecting code into javascript, the more apt choice would just be to hook the function you're modifying.

Comment: @Nowayz I'm not injection code into javascript, i'm injection code into PHP functions :-) That's why i want to ommit any javascript functions. Some people just mix PHP and HTML together. So it's quite possible that they add JS functions in there aswell :-)

Comment: if all your functions are methods you could just as well require public|protected|private to be present

Comment: I'm thinking about it, and it should be possible to do this all in one regex, but I don't have the time to sit down and think about it right now.  If you have a regex helper application I would try to use lookahead and lookbehinds with conditions... you might be able to figure out a working regex for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

If your php functions always have a visibility modifier like `public` you could do:

```
(?:public|protected|private)\s+function\s+\w+\(.*?\)\s*\{
```

Otherwise, you could strip the script part first.
Something like:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<script(?:(?!<\/script>).)*<\/script>/s','',$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, but I know regex:

Your original regex is not so good, since it matches

```
// This is a functional comment { isn't it? }
             ^^^^^^^^...........^
```

Maybe if you make it more robust it will solve your problem:

> > `^\s*(public|protected|private)\s+function\s+\(.*?\).*?{`

This will ensure it is a function declaration for 99% of the cases. There are still some unusual cases where you can fool it.

Answer (score 0):

No amount of regex is going to achieve a decent fail-proof solution.

The right way to do this is with [php tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

```
<?php

$code = <<<END
<?php 
public function Test(\$name) //<--- Match found!
{
    echo 'In test';
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<--- Script tag found, dont do any matches!
$(function() {
    function Test()
    {
        var bla = "In js";
    }
});
</script> //<--- Closed tag, start searching for matches again.
<? 
public function Bla(\$name) //<--- Match found!
{
    echo 'In test';
}
END;


function injectCodeAtFunctionsStart ($originalCode, $code)
{
    $tokens = token_get_all ($originalCode);

    $newTokenTree = '';

    // iterate tokens
    for ($i = 0, $total = count($tokens); $i < $total; $i++) 
    {
        $node = $tokens[$i];
        $newTokenTree[] = $node;

        if (is_array ($node)) 
        {
            // function start
            if ($node[0] == T_FUNCTION) 
            {
                // walk to first brace
                while ($tokens[$i] !== '{') {
                    $newTokenTree[] = $tokens[$i];
                    $i++;
                }
                $i++;

                // keep space
                $space = $tokens[$i];
                $newTokenTree[] = $space;

                // add new piece
                $newTokenTree[] = $code;
                $newTokenTree[] = $space;
            }
        }
    }

    // rebuild code from tokens    
    $content = '';
    foreach ($newTokenTree as $node) {
        $content .= is_scalar ($node) ? $node : $node[1];
    }

    return $content;
}


echo injectCodeAtFunctionsStart ($code, 'echo "new piece";');
```

Comment: Please note that this only works for valid php/html input (ie: code has to start with <? or <?php).